# Hybrid Application Sizes

Tags: flutter, storage, hybrid-mobile-app, flutter-test

Currently, I've been developing an application in flutter but after I install it on my android device I diagnosed that it takes huge amount of space.
Firstly I want to know if there is any solution to it?
Secondly, if there isn't any solution; is there any other hybrid language without this problem??

Comment: what size you get ?, did you try you [split per abi](https://flutter.dev/docs/perf/app-size) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you run `flutter run` and see the application size in your phone you will find it very large > 40 MB. This is because while in debug mode whole flutter engine is installed on phone to support debugging and Just in time compilation of your dart files. Effectively lets you hot reload your changes Just in time.

Now if you run `flutter build apk` or `flutter run --release`, this will generate an apk in release mode. Means no debugging support, everything Ahead of compiled to target machine code. And the size of the app should be as low as possible < 15 MB.